# NTFS SATA Drive mounted in Read-only Mode in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I know this is probably a very common question, but I read most of them and they do not seem to apply to my case; therefore, I am going to ask it in an effort to get this resolved.
I have two separate SSD drives.  One is for Windows 10.  The other is for Ubuntu 22.04. ON the machine, I have a RAID 1E that consists of four TB drives, resulting into a usable six TB space.  I formated this RAID space after installing Windows 10 on the Windows SSD drive and using it to store common data that I would like to access in Ubuntu.
When I want to use Linux, I remove the Windows SSD and insert the Ubuntu SSD and boot.  When The booting process is completed, the RAID is mounted automatically, but it is READ-ONLY.

I installed ntsf-3g and fuser and tried to gain access by adding a line in /etc/fstab with the following:

```
UUID=988694E28694C264  /dev/sda2       ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

After rebooting, the drive is not visible and running a "df -hT" yields the following:

```
/dev/sda2      fuseblk  5.5T  2.4G  5.5T   1% /dev/sda2
```

I also tried to mount from fstab using the following:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/work     ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

This generated the following error:

```
johnny@JS-ML:~$ sudo mount -a
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Here is my question:

How do I setup the system so I can share the data between Windows and Ubuntu equally with the NTFS partition that I created in Windows 10?

Comment: is "fast startup" disabled in Windows?

Comment: Are you referring to the BIOS setting, Fast StartUp?
If that is the case, then, yes; Fast StartUp is active in my BIOS settings.

Comment: no, in windows. https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Comment: when Windows Fast Startup is enabled, Windows doesn't shut down when you click "shut down", but rather goes into a hibernate mode. If Windows was using any drives, then those still are "in use" by Windows, and Ubuntu won't write to them.

Comment: This is a notice not an error "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened."  and it prevent data loss. Please follow up in Esthers comment and disable fast boot in windows to use the disk on non-windows systems.

Comment: Ester's guidelines and recommendations did the trick.  I disable windows' fast Startup and the Disk is now available to Ubuntu as any other drive!  Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

I disabled "fast startup" in Windows and was then able to write to the disk in Ubuntu.  Ester's guidelines and recommendations did the trick. Thank You